# how to return 403 on api-rest grails when invalid role

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have this configuration on application.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
        [pattern: '/',                  access: ['permitAll']],
        [pattern: '/application/index', access: ['permitAll']], // show application index whithout authenticantion.
        [pattern: '/notAuthorized',     access: ['permitAll']], // permitAll to render notAuthorized json.
        [pattern: '/**',            access: ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_OTHER']] // valid paths in api to require authentication.
]
```

In a Controller I have:

```
FooController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
    def action1() {
        /*code*/
    }

    @Secured(['ROLE_OTHER'])
    def action2() {
        /*code*/
    }
}
```

When the user has `ROLE_OTHER` and tries to access `/api/foo/action1` it does not allow it, and it is correct because he does not have permission, however the return status is 404.
I understand that these url's don't map them for roles that don't have permission, but is there a way to devovler `403` instead of `404`?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the Grails API plugin. The BeAPI API plugin automatically checks roles and does this (no additional coding required). You just have to make sure to add the roles to your schema:

```
        "update": {
            "METHOD": "PUT",
            "DESCRIPTION": "Description for update",
                "ROLES": {
                "BATCH": ["ROLE_ADMIN"]
            },
            "REQUEST": {
                "ROLE_ADMIN":["firstName","passwordExpired","accountExpired","oauthProvider","username","accountLocked","password","lastName","oauthId","enabled","avatarUrl","email","id","version"]
            },
            "RESPONSE": {
                "ROLE_ADMIN":["id"]
            }
        },
```

Oh and so no one blocks this response, I am the maintainer of said plugin.